# Why android app is getting slow

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am developing an app that can take pictures using intents and save it to storage. After taking 10 to 15 pictures the app is gets very slow. Code for taking picture is as follows:

```
    private void capturePhoto() {

            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Feedback");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(root, Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME + ".jpeg");
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);


            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, requestCode);


        }
         @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (this.requestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                File file = new File(root, Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME+".jpeg");
                checkFlowIdisPresent(file);

                   displayPic();


            }
        }
 private void displayPic() {

        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "/Feedback/" + Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME + ".jpeg";
        //  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        //Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 300, 300, true);

        File imgFile = new File(filePath);
        Bitmap bmp = decodeFile(imgFile);


        if (imgFile.exists()) {

            dispProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } else {

            dispProfilePic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_image);

        }
    }
```

**Edited** DisplayPic() method is shown above

Comment: You displaying all the pictures together in `ListView` or something?

Comment: my app basically feedback app. am not displaying in listview. am just displaying in an imageview. after taking 10 to 15 feedback servey it becomes slow

Comment: Maybe because you display all picture, you should close last picture if another is taken

Comment: Can you show us the displayPic() method?

Comment: DisplayPic() method is added

Comment: Maybe you should recycle your bitmap after you done with it. I Suspect that the app slows down because it reaches its maximum memory size because you do not recycle your bitmaps. Did you track your memory values?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a image loading library to load the images.

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) is my fav one.

its setup is very simple:

put this n your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

Then your method will be

```
private void displayPic() {
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "/Feedback/" + Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME + ".jpeg";    
    Glide.with(context).load(filePath).override(300, 300).into(dispProfilePic);
}
```

You can find more informatin and usage details [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).